# How to merge the output of these 2 tracking scripts

Tags: grep, echo, sensors

I have 2 scripts:

track_temps.sh

```
while true
do
    echo -n "$(date +"%H:%M:%S"): "
    sensors | grep Tdie

    # Sleeping for X seconds
    sleep 1
done
```

track_mhz.sh

```
    while true
do
    # Printing the time and all temperatures to stdout
    echo -n "$(date +"%H:%M:%S"): "
    cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep "MH" | sort -r | head -1

    # Sleeping for X seconds
    sleep 1
done
```

The output from track_temps.sh looks like:

```
09:31:44: Tdie:         +69.1°C  (high = +70.0°C)
09:31:45: Tdie:         +69.1°C  (high = +70.0°C)
09:31:46: Tdie:         +69.1°C  (high = +70.0°C)
```

The output from track_mhz.sh looks like:

```
09:32:01: cpu MHz       : 4015.803
09:32:02: cpu MHz       : 4008.034
09:32:03: cpu MHz       : 4028.516
```

I would like to merge the output, so that it looks like

```
09:31:44: Tdie:         +69.1°C  (high = +70.0°C) cpu MHz: 4015.803
09:31:45: Tdie:         +69.1°C  (high = +70.0°C) cpu MHz: 4008.034
09:31:46: Tdie:         +69.1°C  (high = +70.0°C) cpu MHz: 4028.516
```

Even better, would be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try

```
while true
do
    echo -n "$(date +"%H:%M:%S"): "
    echo -n "$(sensors | grep Tdie) "
    awk '$2 == "MHz" { if (c< $4) c=$4;} END {printf "cpu MHz %s\n",c}'  /proc/cpuinfo

    sleep 1
done
```

- on my box cpu frequency change from 998 to 1200 MHz, I am not sure `sort -r` will behave as expected. (string "900" is greater than string "1200")

Comment: Thanks for the caveat. Fortunately my MHz figures are 4 digits, so hopefully I won't have the sorting issue. But I will keep it in mind.